# Can we avoid Splunk indexing lines from a file that gets overwritten?

Tags: splunk

We have a process that writes log lines to a log file. Every 15 min the entire log file is overwritten. If there are new lines, those are added. Old lines are retained.

We want the Heavy Forwarder to send to Splunk only the new lines, even though the entire file has got overwritten. Is that possible?

Comment: Have you tried an ordinary `monitor` input?  If the file is identical each time it is written (except for the new lines) then Splunk should remember its position in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing is precisely how the [`[monitor:...]`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/Admin/Inputsconf#inputs.conf.example) stanza of an [`inputs.conf`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/Admin/Inputsconf) works for the [Universal Forwarder](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Forwarder/latest/Forwarder/Abouttheuniversalforwarder)